# Normalization of a database

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I'm trying to turn a database/table into the 3NF. I'm not sure if this is correct or not, can someone give me some pointers?

Link can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f0xujrX2TjEYDcma3lqAN0yyZ4Q4QhIIfvUdeT9ed5U/edit#gid=0

Comment: The spreadsheet seems to lose data in 3NF. Missing cost totals for orders, for example.

Comment: @joshp cost totals can be calculated, as he is keeping current item price with Order itself .

Comment: @AnilKumar Reasonable, but it's probably best to actually say that in the exercise, especially if it's for school. Will the assumption about always calculating cost give you a correct answer? Does 3NF forbid storing aggregates? Is a multirow aggregate a functional dependency?

Comment: @joshp You are right  "3NF does not forbid storing aggregates". And a multirow aggregate can not be always said a trival functional dependency hence If its not for school (like I assumed) then cost totals should also be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3° Normal Form: Last three table should be

Acc No.,    Customer

Acc No.,    Address

Order No.,  Date,   Account No

Comment: What about "item"? Should they not be included as a separate table in the 3NF?

Also, how would be implemented in SQL?

Comment: Item you can use from your 2nf.